# Facebook POP animation works only once

Tags: ios, facebook-pop

I'm using the [Facebook Pop](https://github.com/facebook/pop) library to bounce a view every time something happens in my app. The problem is that the animation works only on the 1st occurrence.

It is easily reproducible with this snippet

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    POPSpringAnimation *sprintAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewScaleXY];
    sprintAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.9, 0.9)];
    sprintAnimation.velocity = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 2)];
    sprintAnimation.springBounciness = 20.f;

    [self.shakeView pop_addAnimation:sprintAnimation forKey:@"springAnimation"];
}
```

The 1st time you tap the button, `shakeView` is animated correctly but not on the taps after.

I tried removing all animation using `[self.shakeView pop_removeAllAnimations]` before adding a new one but it doesn't help.

I think I missed something in the Pop usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. The solution is to set the `removedOnCompletion` to `NO` as follows:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{

    POPSpringAnimation *sprintAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewScaleXY];
    sprintAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.9, 0.9)];
    sprintAnimation.velocity = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 2)];
    sprintAnimation.springBounciness = 20.f;

    sprintAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [self.shakeView pop_addAnimation:sprintAnimation forKey:@"springAnimation"];
}
```